# HTML/CSS: Bootstrap navigation bar isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I am utilizing a Bootstrap Navigation Bar at the top of the webpage. Much like many Bootstrap Navbars, this particular one collapses when the page reaches a certain length, and all of the headings go into a button on the top right corner of the page. The problem is, when the button is clicked, the Navbar does not show the headings.

And here's the catch: On this one page in particular, and just this one page, the bar does not work. In fact, the button seems to be greyed out.

(I would provide images, but Stackoverflow does not let me place links because I am a new user)

I have tried substituting Navbars from other pages with this page - does not work.

AND

I have tried substituting this Navbar  with Navbars from other pages - works perfectly fine.

This leads me to believe that there is something else on this page that is casuing the Navbar to be "disabled" or there is something causing it to be not shown, such as a missing tag. I've done a complete search of my code and can not find it.

As I said previously, the problem is, it is on only one page in particular; none others. Given that someone is willing to search though my source code, I have provided some source code below to find errors in the syntax.

Also, note well that I have included a Lightbox photo gallery in my code, and have placed external links and scripts at the bottom.

```
<head> <!--HEAD START-->
    <meta name="description" content="Description"/>
    <meta name="keyword" content="keyword"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.jpg"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <script language="JavaScript" rel="text/javascript" src="js/logic.js"></script>
    <title> Title </title>
</head><!--HEAD END-->

<body><!--BODY START-->
    <noscript>
        Please enable JavaScript to view this page's content
    </noscript>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Navbar Title</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="theassociation.html">The Association</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Photo Gallery </a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="container"><!--CONTAINER START-->
            <div class="jumbotron"><!--JUMBOTRON START-->
                <h1> Title </h1>
                <h6> Lorem ipsum dolar sit amat </h6>
            </div><!--JUMBOTRON END-->
     </div><!--CONTAINER END-->
    <hr/>
    <div class="page-header" id="heading2">
        <h2> Photo Gallery <br/> <small class="style"> See pictures from the 2015-2016 Season </small></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <hr/>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="photoData" data-title="..." data-lightbox="..."><img src="img/IMG_7561.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" width="200px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <footer class="footer"><!--FOOTER START-->

            <div class="container">
                <p class="text-muted">
                    &copy; <script> writeDate(); </script>, All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer><!--FOOTER END-->

<!-- SCRIPTS MUST BE PLACED AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE FOR PROPER EXECUTION OF ELEMENTS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" rel="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body><!--BODY END-->
</html>
```

Comment: You're calling 2 different Bootstrap CSS versions in the head and you have two jQuery calls in the footer. Start by removing the extras and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the bootstrap javascript library?

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`